# get Keys from IgniteCache

Tags: java, ignite

I have to get all keys stored in IgniteCache, unfortunately this method is not implemented in Ignite. I'm using java client. 
I thought it is a common method, what is the reason Ignite team didn't implement it?

Is there any efficient solution for getting keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get all the keys using [ScanQuery](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.1/docs/cache-queries#scan-queries) with a `null` predicate. It will return all the entries (key-value pairs).
As well you can use an [SqlFieldsQuery](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.1/docs/sql-queries#section-sqlfieldsqueries) like `select _key from Entity`

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @alexfedotov I created a solution for my problem, I'm positng it here, since someone may find it useful.

```
List<K> keys = new ArrayList<>();
cache.query(new ScanQuery<>(null)).forEach(entry -> keys.add((K) entry.getKey()));
```

After running this code you will receive a list with keyset.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for getting all keys from cache :

```
ICache<string, object> cache = ignite.GetCache<string, object>(cacheName);
List<string> cacheKeys = cache.Select(e => e.Key).ToList();
```